# jquery form submit with confirmation in a modal

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I've used some code from another question asked years ago
[Implement jQuery confirmation modal in a form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037634/implement-jquery-confirmation-modal-in-a-form-submit/17037698#17037698)

but that question didn't go far enough to show how a form could be submitted when responding with Yes and I haven't been able to get this to work.

You will see all the ways I've tried to make work (they are commented out).
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
     <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ready?">
         <p>Are you sure?</p>
     </div>

    <form action"" id="myform" name="myform2" type="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="moveOn" />
    </form>

     <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
         resizable: false,
         height:190,
         autoOpen: false,
         width: 330,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
           "Yes": function() {
             //$('#myform')[0].submit();
             //document.myform2.submit();
             //document.getElementById("#myform").submit();

              },
        No: function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");
         }
     }

   });

    $('#myform').submit(function() {
       $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
       return false;
       });

       });
```

Comment: Here is working solution that is answered before: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks..but those solutions don't use a modal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one here. Instead of putting a submit button, make the button a normal button and handle its click event. Then you just submit the form if the user clicks *Yes*. You also have some syntax errors like this unneeded form action `<form action""`, remove the action at all, you're posting at the same form.

**Your code slightly changed**

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ready?">
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="moveOn" value="Yes" />
    <input type="button" id="moveOn" value="Yes" />
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 190,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 330,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    $('#myform').submit();
                },
                No: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#moveOn').on('click', function(e) {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code to use a hidden field to pass the `moveOn` post variable to PHP. The changes inside the form are:

```
<input type="hidden" name="moveOn" value="Yes" />
<input type="button" id="moveOn" value="Yes" />
```

**UPDATE 2**

It appears you have one more error that prevents the form from submitting the data. It's the form `type="post"` which of course is incorrect and to set the correct form method you need to use `method="post"`:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post">
...
</form>
```

You can try my example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/submit-confirm/

Here is a screen capture with my example working:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

I suppose you already have a PHP code that handles the POST data at the beggining of the script, like this one here:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['moveOn']) && $_POST['moveOn'] == 'Yes') {
    echo '<h3>The form was posted!</h3>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Take a look here..  https://usc.thrivezone.org/z.php  I have this code if (isset($_REQUEST['moveOn']) && $_REQUEST['moveOn']=='Yes'){
 echo "submitted";
} that should result in the word submitted being echo, but it's not..am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Allen Yes you have absolutely right! Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Allen Yes, you need to change the `<form type="post"` with `<form method="post"`. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experiencing is: when you click YES the submit handler is called again.

To solve this you may use the [trigger event with extraParameters](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters) in order to distinguish if the submit is triggered from within the dialog or not.

Because the dialog is asynchronous you can use a deferred approach, an old answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722811/jqueryui-dialog-replacement-for-confirm/38723372#38723372).

The code and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2rz6ygw/):

```js
$(function () {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:190,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 330,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        //
        // Instead to submit the form trigger the
        // submit event with a parameter.....
        //
        $('#myform').trigger('submit', true);
      },
      No: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    //
    // Test if the submit event has been triggered from within the dialog
    //
    alert(arguments.length);
    if (!(arguments.length == 2 && arguments[1] === true)) {
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
      return false;
    } else {
       // submitted
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ready?">
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form action="" id="myform" name="myform2" type="post">
<input type="submit" value="Yes" name="moveOn" />
</form>
```

Comment: seems like this should work..I added what you suggest but it still doesn't submit (even when I try to run the code snippet on this site)

Comment: yes, you can see it here (running on a cloud server) https://usc.thrivezone.org/z.php

Comment: it doesn't, at least for me.  It should say "submitted" after it successfully submits.

Comment: ok..I put your exact code on my site usc.thrivezone.org/z.php and I'm still not getting it to submit (I took out the alerts you added).  As for message after it submit, I just want it to submit and I'm using php to echo submitted if it actually submits.

Comment: Ok..when I use a plain on return confirm, like on this video, you can see I get a response of submitted.  This is not what I'm getting using the other code.   https://db.tt/k7wHUgPis

Comment: here is the correct link   https://www.dropbox.com/s/sd49wwr2nrsxc8g/2016-12-04_16-10-55.mp4?dl=0

Comment: @Allen the message you see after submitting is generated from the php server side: if the php runs as a post request a new message is added to the page. For more details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/detecting-request-type-in-php-get-post-put-or-delete

Comment: right..I've had that code on my page for the last day or so.

Comment: @Allen I'm glad for you.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution would be to set a flag that checks if you already clicked "Yes":

```
$(function() {
  var postForm = false;
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:190,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 330,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        postForm = true;
        $('#myform').submit();
      },
      "No": function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(!postForm) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
    } else {
      console.log('form submitting...')
    }
  });
});
```

See here for a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3013ch5h/)

Another solution would be to disable the submitting of the form (using e.preventDefault()) and to post the data of the form manually after clicking "Yes" using AJAX:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:190,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 330,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: $('#myform').attr('action'),
          data: $('#myform').serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
            console.log('form submitted');
          }
        });
      },
      "No": function() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks..well, you can see the first solution here, which doesn't appear to submit   https://usc.thrivezone.org/z.php   I can't really use an ajax solution because of the way the site works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: 190,
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 330,
  modal: true,
  buttons: [{
    text: "Yes",
    click: function() {
      console.log("ASD");
      $(this).dialog("close");

      $('#myform').attr("data-submit", "true").submit();
    }
  }, {
    text: "No",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }]
});

$('#myform').on("submit", function() {
  var attr = jQuery(this).attr("data-submit");
  if (attr == "false") {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ready?">
  <p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form action='www.google.com' id="myform" name="myform2" type="post" data-submit="false">
  <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="moveOn" />
</form>
```

This should be working.

Html:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Ready?">
<p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<form action='www.google.com' id="myform" name="myform2" type="post" data-submit="false">
<input type="submit" value="Yes" name="moveOn" />
```

JS:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height: 190,
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 330,
  modal: true,
  buttons: [{
    text: "Yes",
    click: function() {
      console.log("ASD");
      $(this).dialog("close");

      $('#myform').attr("data-submit", "true").submit();
    }
  }, {
    text: "No",
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }]
});

$('#myform').on("submit", function() {
  var attr = jQuery(this).attr("data-submit");
  if (attr == "false") {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
    return false;
  }
});
```

And a working [jsfiddl](https://jsfiddle.net/pg6hmzp6/).

Comment: Thanks....this is getting confusing...I see this works in jsfiddle, but if you go here (where I've  copied your code), its not firing off the modal.  https://usc.thrivezone.org/z.php   Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can remove this line alert(attr);. Generally, if you want to debug JS code a better way is to use console.log("error title", "message", anyVar, anotherVar, .. );

Comment: Also, now when using exactly your code here usc.thrivezone.org/z.php   the modal opens and then submits before any clicks happen.

Comment: The code has an error at $('#myform')..on('submit', function(e). You need to place one "." So it should be $('#myform').on('submit', function(e)

Comment: thanks..fixed that...now if you try it again, it won't work since it immediately submits

Comment: You have another error: "elem.getClientRects is not a function". To fix it check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914869/jquery-ui-error-f-getclientrects-is-not-a-function

Comment: I'm not getting this error..that reference looks like is for a different problem....how are you seeing this in my code (which is actually your code)?

Comment: It is a different problem. But for JS code to work the page should be JS error-free. I am seeing this error using firebug. You can use any browser developer tool and check the console section to see the error.

Comment: yes, I've been using firebug...here is a video of your exact code on my server and you'll see no errors and it submits immediately  https://db.tt/pnXER8LyhK

Comment: Next to console word in console tab there is an arrow. Click on it and make sure that "Show JavaScript Error" option is enabled. Reload the page and try again.

Comment: see here https://db.tt/Ol0usBBLX5   all javascript errors enabled...and it submits immediately